# Display large set of data from http in drop down using angular 4/6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to bind Angular-4 drop-down   with around 10,000+ records, it's hanging application.
What I want is to display drop-down options in chuck/slice.
Eg: On page load display only 8 data in drop-down & when user scroll down then pop-out this data & load/push other 8 data in drop-down.
The acceptance criteria is that I can't use jquery & third party plugin in my project. Please help me getting out of this.
I am using PrimeFaces Library in myproject. So, Is that possible to do the same in it?

Here is the code but it is not working and neither the **onScrollDown** has been trigeered

```
loadMcr() {
    this.LogicService.GetMr().then((data) => {
      this.mrList = data;
      this.mrListing = this.mrList.slice(0, 10);

    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
onScrollDown() {
if (this.mrListing.length < this.mrList.length) {
  let len = this.mrListing.length;

  for (var i = len; i <= len + 20; i++) {
    this.mrListing.push(this.mrList[i]);
  }
}
}

<li>
<select id="largeData" formControlName="mydata" (change)="onScrollDown()">
<option *ngFor="let option of mrListing"  [ngValue]="option.id">{{option.description}}</option>
</select>
</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Why you want to do sth like this? Most likely your browser is gonna freeze and become unresponsive.

Comment: I know @kboul but this is the acceptance criteria of my project and i have to give POC for that.

Comment: You are probably looking for a virtual-scroll component. I create a quite simple version of it here https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/823#issuecomment-333805921 in a month, you will be able to use @angular/cdk version of virtual-scroll when version 7 releases.

Comment: Thanks @Ploppy but i need this in select option drop-down !

Comment: You can create your own custom drop-down element modal with @angular/cdk.

Comment: @Ploppy ..You have any?
I am new in angular actually.

Comment: This is **_NOT_** PrimeFaces related... Click [tag:PrimeFaces] and read it... it might be PrimeNG related...